# Systematic anticoagulant injection after a CVA

Tags: neuroscience, brain

Since most of the cerebrovascular accident are ischemic ones, would it be usefull to have anticoagulant everywhere (we already have  AEDs everywhere) so that everytime someone would have symptoms of a CVA we would be able to destroy the blood clot before any permanent damage to occur ?

On the other hand may it make the case of ruptured aneurysm getting worse ?

So what are the potential negative and positive effect of such a policy ?

Comment: I think it would be useful to rephrase this to ask for the potential positive and negative effects of anticoagulants. Right now the question is close to [*primarily opinion-based*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).